# Javascript: Times table, make first cell blank, trying to get this output

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my code for creating a table given a users input :

```js
const err = "the valid input is a number between 5 and 20, please refresh your page to start again";

const q1 = "Enter a value";
var user = prompt(q1);
var x = parseInt(user, 10);

if (Number.isInteger(x) && x >= 5) {
  x = x;
  if (x >= 20) {
    document.getElementById("rer").innerHTML = err;
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("rer").innerHTML = err;
}

function timestable(x) {
  var r, s;
  document.write("<table id = 'table' border = 1")

  for (r = 1; r <= x; r++) {
    document.write("<tr>")
    for (s = 1; s <= x; s++) {

      document.write("<td>" + r * s + "</td>")

    }
    document.write("</tr>")
  }
  document.write("</table>")
}
console.log(timestable(x));
```

This is the output when you enter 10 :

[image: example of output when user input 10]

**I want the first cell, where the 1 is currently occupying, to be blank.** I also want the **next cel**l to the right to **start at 1**, and I want the next cell below it to also start at 1, and then continue the pattern.

Is there any way to apply this fix to my current code?

Comment: Sounds like all you need to do is insert an empty <td> element just before you begin your loop. Also, you may want to consider appending child nodes instead of using document.write.

Comment: Change `document.write("<tr>")` to `document.write("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td>")`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your two `for` loops to begin with 0, and change what you print in the cells:

```
for (r = 0; r <= x; r++) {
   document.write("<tr>")
   for (s = 0; s <= x; s++) {
     if (s === 0 && r === 0) {
        product = '';
     } else if (s === 0) {
        product = r;
     } else if (r === 0) {
        product = s;
     } else {
        product = r * s;
     }
     document.write("<td>" + product + "</td>")
   }
}
```

See it [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf8v5zLb/2/)